# Enable existing users to change email with Meteor's accounts-ui

Tags: meteor

The `{{> loginButtons}}` component in Meteor's [`account-ui`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/accounts-ui.html) implements an UI for managing user accounts (signup, login, change password etc). However, how to configure it to allow an existing user to change his/her email address?

Answer (score 0):

> how to configure it to allow an existing user to change his/her email address?

You can't. It's limited to [what `Accounts.ui.config` provides](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Accounts-ui-config).

You need to implement a Meteor Method that forwards the email to [Accounts.addEmail](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-addEmail):

```js
Meteor.methods({
  addEmail ({ email }) {
    const { userId } = this
    Accounts.addEmail(userId, email)
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, email)
  }
})
```

If the user has verified the new email you can safely remove the old email after login:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  removeEmail ({ email }) {
    const { userId } = this
    Accounts.removeEmail(userId, email)
  }
})
```

Note: if you remove the old email when adding the new one, user may lock themselves out, which is why you should remove the old email only after verification.

Another note: on the client you need to provide a form for the new Email, of course that on submit sends the new email to the `addEmail` Method via

```js
Meteor.call('addEmail', email, (err, res) => {...})
```